Bundling Node.js app with Dependency that Includes a .node (Node Addon) File
I'm trying to create a bundle that includes a module that itself includes a .module file or Node Addon. The file it's self is binary so my bundler is struggling to understand how to deal with it.
From the docs the file can be referenced with a require('filename') and it's loaded the same as any script. Because of that I think I'm hitting a hard stop here. The bundler would normally take all the source and dependencies and combine them into one file. When those files are text they can be included or transpiled into the output file as has been done for years when not binary.
Is there some way to include the binary data, the .node file, into my output file, say as base64, while still having it loaded as it would have with a require(...)?
